# Web3.eth.getBalance(...).toNumber() returns huge number

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, truffle

I am using Truffle [MetaCoin](https://github.com/katopz/truffle-metacoin-example) box in **truffle develop** mode. The front end tries to get the balance of an account but gets a huge number.

The front end code is the following:

```
var coinbase = web3.eth.coinbase;
var balance = web3.eth.getBalance(coinbase).toNumber();
```

More specifically, by default the first account truffle generates should has 10k balance. After running one test as in the link above. Its balance should be 9990. This works correctly if I `console.log` it in test file.

But the `balance` variable I got from front end is 100000000000000000000. After test it goes to 99917820100000000000. This difference is clearly not 10 or its exponential.

Why and how to fix this?

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're interested in the token balance or the ether balance? It seems like there might be confusion between the two. You're measuring the ether balance (100000000000000000000 wei is 10 ether, and 99835640200000000000 is presumably the ether balance after paying for gas for some test cases).

Comment: transaction fees

Comment: Transaction fee of 6.43598? The return value is in wei, per the documentation, so it’s a big integer: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetbalance

Comment: @Ryan but the OP is not using the real ethereum blockchain right now

Answer (score 3):

It's just showing the balance in wei, or ether * `10^18`, so in other words instead of `.000000000000000001` ether it shows `1`.

Divide everything by `1e18` if you want whole numbers, it most likely does this to avoid floating point errors.  According to their docs a test account starts with 10 ether, and 10,000 MetaCoins, which is where your confusion is.

And the reason your 2nd number isn't 9990000... is because of a transaction fee

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `1e16` issue. But I noticed one thing, I actually ran test **twice**. After one test the remaining balance is `9991.78201` which is more than `9990`. This is wired. How come after gas fee, it gets more?

Answer (score 3):

`web3.eth.getBalance()` returns the ether balance of the account, in wei. There are 10^18 wei in an ether. `100000000000000000000` wei is 10 ether, which I imagine is the default starting balance of accounts in your local test network. `99917820100000000000` is presumably the amount of ether remaining after paying for gas for the test cases you ran.

You're expecting to see a balance of 10,000 because you're thinking of the number of *MetaCoins* that are supposed to be owned by the account. (This is unrelated to the amount of ether.)

To get the number of MetaCoins, you would need to call `balanceOf(account)` on the `MetaCoin` contract. If you look through the test code, you'll see that's what it's doing to check the account's MetaCoin balance.